# Doughnut chart showing monthly spend

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm using Excel 2016.

I want to produce a dashboard graph (visually a doughnut would work best) that shows the amount of money spent each month.

I have a column with dates and a column with money, but can't figure out how to get these to filter between the monthly date ranges, adding up the total spent within that time period.

I need this to be dynamic as I enter dates and costs automatically adding up the values per month.

[Data Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qhtTuLA2uvNjJxdGZWUnFuQ29PYUxCMEZJbFJMRXBsMkg0/view?usp=sharing)

I am interested in column A (Dates) and column C (Money).

Comment: Some people won't download files from unknown sources. Better to include sample data and the expected result in your question by [editing it](https://superuser.com/posts/1517951/edit)

Comment: Wouldn't a line chart of date (X axis) vs money (Y axis) work best? Donut charts are pretty, but I don't think they're suited for plotting values against time.